# Printing out the fibonacci series

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures, fibonacci

I am trying to write a simple Python program. It's supposed to return a a closure that returns successive fibonacci numbers:

```
def fibGen():
    n_1 = 0
    n_2 = 0 
    n = 1
    def fib():
        if n_1 ==0 and n_2 ==0:
            n_1 = 1
            return n
        else:
            n = n_1 + n_2
            n_2 = n_1
            n_1 = n  
            return n
    return fib

f = fibGen()
for i in range(0,10):
    print(f())
```

I get this error at run time:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n_1' referenced before assignment`

EDIT: In my original post, I had not included `n = 1` in the definition of `fibGen` but it was actually a typo. I would still get the same error anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python determines the scope of variables at compile time, based on *binding behaviour*. If you assign to a name, or use it as an `import` target (and a few other ways) you are binding the name in a scope.

You are binding to `n_1` and `n_2` in the `fib()` function; both are being assigned to. This makes those two names *local* in `fib()`, and Python won't even look at the surrounding scope.

You'll need to override this behaviour, and you can do this by using the [`nonlocal` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

```
def fibGen():
    n_1 = 0
    n_2 = 0 
    def fib():
        nonlocal n_1, n_2
        if n_1 ==0 and n_2 ==0:
            n_1 = 1
            return n
        else:
            n = n_1 + n_2
            n_2 = n_1
            n_1 = n  
            return n
    return fib
```

`nonlocal` tells the compiler *explicitly* that you don't want it to look at binding behaviour but instead treat the names as closures.

Next, you are using `n` in the first branch of the `if` test, but you haven't defined it anywhere outside of the `else` branch. You should just return `1` there anyway:

```
def fibGen():
    n_1 = 0
    n_2 = 0 
    def fib():
        nonlocal n_1, n_2
        if n_1 ==0 and n_2 ==0:
            n_1 = 1
            return n_1
        else:
            n = n_1 + n_2
            n_2 = n_1
            n_1 = n  
            return n
    return fib
```

Last but not least, you can swap two variables by using tuple assignment, no intermediaries needed:

```
def fibGen():
    n_1 = 0
    n_2 = 0 
    def fib():
        nonlocal n_1, n_2
        if n_1 ==0 and n_2 ==0:
            n_1 = 1
        else:
            n_1, n_2 = n_1 + n_2, n_1
        return n_1
    return fib
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modified enclosing variables, n_1, n_2 is in `enclosing` space not in space of function that's why you can't cahnge the variables.

Use `nonlocal` keyword

```
def fibGen():
    n_1 = 0
    n_2 = 0 
    def fib():
        nonlocal n_1, n_2
        if n_1 ==0 and n_2 ==0:
            n_1 = 1
            return n_1 # return `n_1` here not `n`
        else:
            n = n_1 + n_2
            n_2 = n_1
            n_1 = n  
            return n
    return fib

f = fibGen()
for i in range(0,10):
    print(f())
```

Comment: @novice66 But my answer is good to explain what's the problem in your code.

Comment: I know, that's why I "upvoted" it to cancel the downvote you got from someone else.

Comment: Interesting that answers like this can now be posted without mention that it is a py3 feature.  Maybe we're finally over the py2->py3 tipping point.

Also, +1 because you look like you were 1 minute ahead of the accepted answer but that answer uses your same function, vaiable names and all.  People with <300K need some upvote lovin' too.

Answer (score 0):

I have been reviewing some of these well known algorithms and thought I'd share my version of fibonacci using closures in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def fibonacci():
    a = 0
    b = 1

    def internal_fibonacci():
        nonlocal a, b
        a, b = b, a+b
        return a
    return internal_fibonacci


def main():
    f = fibonacci()
    for i in range(0,10):
        print("f(" + str(i) + ") => " + str(f()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A bit more elegant than other solutions offered here.